# Error installing Tensorflow in docker image

Tags: windows, python-3.x, docker, tensorflow

I am trying to install tensorflow in docker image for my application.

I have 3 files in the folder which i am using to build image.`Dockerfile`, `index.py` and `requirements.txt`

Contents of these files are

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:alpine3.7
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD python ./index.py
```

**requirements.txt**

```
tensorflow==1.1.0
scikit-learn==0.18.2
scipy==0.19.1
numpy==1.13.1
requests==2.18.3
```

**index.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int("5000"), debug=True)
```

I navigate in the commandline to the folder where i have these 3 files in my windows machine and execute the command `docker build --tag my-python-app2 .`

After a while, after executing a while, i get below error message.

```
C:\Users\test\Downloads\python-docker2>docker build --tag my-python-app2 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
Step 1/6 : FROM python:alpine3.7
 ---> cc07d9ec6532
Step 2/6 : COPY . /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 600334d62435
Step 3/6 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 15208b829606
Step 4/6 : RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in e202ecdc48ba
Collecting tensorflow==1.1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: What version of `pip3` is inside that image? Before `step 4` what happens if you try to upgrade `pip3` first to the latest version?

Comment: I just tried that and added `RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip` before `RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt` and still got the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer myself. I changed the line for tensorflow to `RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl` in **Dockerfile** and removed it from requirements.txt

Comment: You said you are working on a Windows machine, so why are you using Mac `.whl` file?

Comment: I am facing same problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70337271/why-tensorflow-cpu-2-7-0-is-not-found-by-docker-while-creating-an-image do you have any solution?