# How to Install Tensorflow in firebase cloud function

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-functions

I've installed Tensorflow but it does not work. I've installed Tensorflow by using Dockerfile. Adding the commend

```
RUN pip install tensorflow==2.3.
```

When I import tensorflow from main.py, It shows **Service Unavailable**.

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

Actually, I'm new in python. I'm not able to find out the problem. Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can find the answer here: ([Error installing Tensorflow in docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52521190/error-installing-tensorflow-in-docker-image)) "RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl in Dockerfile and removed it from requirements.txt"